# Dataset Normalization in python

Tags: python, numpy, normalization

I am working on a dataset which has entries like this

```
dataset=np.array([[2104,    3],[1600,   3],
                  [2400,    3],[1416,   2],
                  [3000,    4],[1985,   4],
                  [1534,    3],[1427,   3],
                  [1380,    3],[1494,   3],
                  [1940,    4],[2000,   3],
                  [1890,    3],[4478,   5],
                  [1268,    3]])
```

as obvious, all the entries are of type ***int32*** and I also need to scale the features on same scale. So when I try to normalize them using standard normalization(z) of statistics 
which is

```
z=(x-mean)/sigma
```

All the values in dataset becomes becomes zero.
I am using vectorized method. Here is the code.

```
me=[]
sd=[]
for i in range(dataset.shape[1]):
    m=np.mean(dataset[:,i])
    sdd=np.std(dataset[:,i])
    dataset[:,i]=(dataset[:,i]-m)
    dataset[:,i]=dataset[:,i]/sdd
    me.append(m)
    sd.append(sdd)
```

[image: after executing code]

this is what I am getting when I execute the above code snip.

Answer (score 1):

No need to loop. You can use numpy's `std` and `mean` taken along the first axis:

```
(dataset-dataset.mean(0))/dataset.std(0)

array([[ 0.13736137, -0.39223227],
       [-0.49430039, -0.39223227],
       [ 0.50833732, -0.39223227],
       [-0.72490707, -1.86310328],
       [ 1.2603156 ,  1.07863874],
       [-0.01178099,  1.07863874],
       [-0.577018  , -0.39223227],
       [-0.7111208 , -0.39223227],
       [-0.77002576, -0.39223227],
       [-0.62714989, -0.39223227],
       [-0.06817936,  1.07863874],
       [ 0.00701846, -0.39223227],
       [-0.13084422, -0.39223227],
       [ 3.11268878,  2.54950976],
       [-0.91039504, -0.39223227]])
```

---

Or you can also use sklearn's [`StandardScaler`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit_transform(dataset)

array([[ 0.13736137, -0.39223227],
       [-0.49430039, -0.39223227],
       [ 0.50833732, -0.39223227],
       [-0.72490707, -1.86310328],
       [ 1.2603156 ,  1.07863874],
       [-0.01178099,  1.07863874],
       [-0.577018  , -0.39223227],
       [-0.7111208 , -0.39223227],
       [-0.77002576, -0.39223227],
       [-0.62714989, -0.39223227],
       [-0.06817936,  1.07863874],
       [ 0.00701846, -0.39223227],
       [-0.13084422, -0.39223227],
       [ 3.11268878,  2.54950976],
       [-0.91039504, -0.39223227]])
```

Comment: Well you can use numpy..? @majid

Comment: Secondly I have to save mean and standard deviations of all features

Comment: That' was not part of the question @majid

Answer (score 0):

I can see by a naked eye thay you are overusing `dataset[:,i]` value too many times. This is antipattern. Well, what if you do some refactoring to make your script more readable?

```
me, sd=[], []
for i in range(dataset.shape[1]):
    X = dataset[:,i]
    m=np.mean(X)
    sdd=np.std(X)
    X=(X-m)
    X=X/sdd
    me.append(m)
    sd.append(sdd)
```

And, since `me` and `sd` don't help to minimise your example, even more:

```
for i in range(dataset.shape[1]):
    X = dataset[:,i]
    dataset[:,i] = (X-np.mean(X))/np.std(X)
```

By the way, using list operations such as `append` is not adviseable while working with `numpy`. Now

```
dataset = dataset.astype(float)
for i in range(dataset.shape[1]):
    X = dataset[:,i]
    dataset[:,i] = (X-np.mean(X))/np.std(X)
```

does the trick.